# Rails/SQL combine where conditions for rails scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to get total count of items with language_id other than [30, 54] and language_id: nil

```
LOCALES = {
  non_arabic_languages: {
    id: [30, 54]
  }
}

  scope :non_arabic_languages, -> { where.not(language_id: LOCALES[:non_arabic_languages][:id]) || where(language_id: nil) }
```

This example predictably returns first part, so I only get non arabic items. && works wrong as well. How may I combine it? We'll be thankful for the advice!

Comment: Very close just swap the logical or (`||`) for the [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#or`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/or) e.g. `where.not(language_id: LOCALES[:non_arabic_languages][:id]).or(where(language_id: nil))`

Comment: and for Rails 4?

Comment: `where(Model.arel_table[:language_id].not_in(LOCALES[:non_arabic_languages][:id]).or(Model.arel_table[:language_id].eq(nil)))` both will result in `WHERE language_id NOT IN (30,54) OR language_id IS NULL`

Comment: Is this double negation here? If a language is not in the list of non-arabic languages, that makes it arabic, doesn't it?

Comment: There's total list of langs, arabic_langs and non_arabic_langs(called "other_langs"). Also there's an issue when language_id = nil, items doesn't count. let's nil value will be with other_langs:)

Comment: @КонстантинГришунин in this case, looks like you don't need that `where.not`. Just `where`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're falling into a common trap where you confuse logical operations in Ruby with actually creating SQL via the ActiveRecord query interface.

Using `||` will return the first truthy value:

```
where.not(language_id: LOCALES[:non_arabic_languages][:id]) || where(language_id: nil)
```

Which is the ActiveRecord relation returned by `where.not(language_id: LOCALES[:non_arabic_languages][:id])` since everything except false and nil are truthy in Ruby. `|| where(language_id: nil)` is never actually evaluated.

Support for `.or` was added in Rails 5. In previous versions the most straight forward solution is to use Arel or a SQL string:

```
scope :non_arabic_languages, -> { 
  non_arabic_languages_ids = LOCALES[:non_arabic_languages].map { |h| h[:id] }
  where(arel_table[:language_id].not_in(non_arabic_languages_ids ).or(arel_table[:language_id].eq(nil)))
}
```

I would leave a tagging comment (like @fixme) so that you fix this after upgrading to 5.0 or consider a better solution that doesn't involve hardcoding database ids in the first place like for example using a [natural key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes).